# What effects is Clapton using in Badge?

Tags: guitar, identify-this-effect

I am wondering about the album version.

Specifically when the song goes into the chorus.  (Don't you know that the wheel goes round and round...)  The effect is probably best heard as he starts the section before the lyrics.

It sounds like reverb and maybe chorus.  But I'm not too familiar with chorus.

Comment: You might have better luck asking this on https://music.stackexchange.com/ . It's really more of a practitioners' question.

Comment: @ChrisSunami.  Thanks.  It's borderline.  Questions like these usually will pass, but not without some grief.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a fast Leslie. If you Google "Cream Badge effect" you'll find it's much discussed.